# ApplicationError when trying to implement an edited version of the Secure module

Tags: java, security, playframework

I'm implementing an edited version of the Secure controller, default in the latest Play Framework.

I have read several times that, if you want to customize the Secure behaviour, you're better off copying the source of the Secure module, and start customizing it.

So I did, and after editing the needed dependencies I received following error:

```
    Execution exception
NullPointerException occured : null

In /app/controllers/SecureController.java (around line 194)

190:
                 security = classes.get(0);
191:
             }
192:
             if(security==null)System.out.println("security is null");
193:
             try {
194:
                 return Java.invokeStaticOrParent(security, m, args);
195:
             } catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
196:
                 throw e.getTargetException();
197:
             }
198:
         }
199:

200:
     }
```

The first logic conclusion to jump to is: there are no classes that implement the needed Secure$Security inner class. But there most certainly is a subclass, so I was wondering how this error can be fixed.

A debugging session learns that the classes.get(0) does contain the class that has the @With annotation. So the null pointer exception must be caused by something within the class that contains the @With(SecureController). But I left that class just the way it was, I just edited the reference within the With annotation.

So my guess is that somehow, there is a null pointer within the class implementation.
But even when I implement default behaviour, without any references, it still generates a nullpointerexception.

EDIT:
I found the cause of this error, but the 'why' isn't clear.
This line is found in the implementation of the authenticate(...) method in the subclass of SecureController$Security:

```
flash.put("url", request.url);
```

Why does this fail?

I understand this situation may be very hard to reproduce, but I was wondering if someone already experienced the same issue.

Thanks for the help (on many Play! related topics) so far.

Comment: I have the feeling that the request object isn't what I need when I want to find out where the controller has been called... suggestions?

Comment: It's strange, I read the code of secure module from 1.1.1 and I wonder if you have the same code as me :)... what do you do to test your secure module? did you modify anything within the code? do you have the full stacktrace, it would be instructive... regards

Comment: @mandubian Thanks for the anwser. As I said in the post above, I'm customizing the Secure Module to my own whishes. They advised me to do so, so I did :)

I'm testing with a small .yml that creates a new user in the membased-db.

Now that I implemented my solution (see the edit in my post) I don't seem to be able to reproduce the error.

My guess was that, somewhere, I referenced the request.url object, which was null at that time.

I'm reading here and there you should be using response.getCurrent().getHeader("url"). Is this correct?

Comment: It depends where you are and where you call the code... I think this is also not the right code... something like "Request request = Request.current();" would be better... If you are in a controller, the threadlocal request shall be provided by Play so if your request is null, it means you are outside the classical Controler mechanism from Play... without your code, I can't say much more...

Answer (score 0):

the `Scope.Flash` class does not allow you to store `null` values. Perhaps you unset or failed to set `request.url` elsewhere in your modifications?